# How do I use cell values from an Excel worksheet as input?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I need to write a code that will go through a sheet of an Excel file (.xlsx)
and then use those values from the cell one by one via WebDriver.

To be more specific, one sheet holds search engines links and another sheet holds queries.

I only need you to help me figure out how to use the links from the Excel file, 
and not as hard coded values, a way to iterate through them.

This is what I have so far:

```
package a.utilities;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import a.utilities.ChromeDriverInit;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class ExcelUtils {
    static WebDriver driver;
    protected static XSSFSheet excelWSheet;
    protected static XSSFWorkbook excelWBook;
    private static XSSFCell cell;
    private static XSSFRow row;
    //
    static String web;
    static String query;

    // Setting the file to read from
    public static void setExcelFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream file = null;

        try {
            file = new FileInputStream("ExcelWorkSheets/SearchEngines.xlsx");
            excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    file.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Counting the used rows in every work sheet and give you the work sheets data
    public static void getSheetData() {
        int index = 0;  
        for (int i = 0; i < excelWBook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            index++;
            System.out.println("Sheet Name: " + "["
                    + excelWBook.getSheetName(i) + "] --> " + "Sheet index: "
                    + "[" + index + "]\n");

        }
        int rowIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < excelWBook.getSheetAt(0).getLastRowNum()+1; i++) {
            excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheetAt(0);
            rowIndex++;

        }
        System.out.println("Number of rows including the header: --> " + rowIndex);
        System.out.println("Number of rows not including the header: --> " +excelWSheet.getLastRowNum());
        System.out.println();


        int rowIndex2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < excelWBook.getSheetAt(1).getLastRowNum()+1; i++) {
            excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheetAt(1);
            rowIndex2++;

        }
        System.out.println("Number of rows including the header: --> " + rowIndex2);
        System.out.println("Number of rows not including the header: --> " +excelWSheet.getLastRowNum());
        System.out.println();


    // Going through the SearchEngines work sheet to get the data from every used cell and prints it out

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = excelWSheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    web = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(web + "\t\t");

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        // Going through the queries work sheet to get the data from every used cell and prints it out
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator2 = excelWSheet.iterator();
            while(rowIterator2.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator2.next();

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
    }
```

This does go through the list, but how do I pass it on so WebDriver would be able to use this values?

Comment: Instead of printing it to `System.out.println(...)` save values to an `ArrayList` and pass that to WebDriver.

Comment: Sorry my java skills aren't that good, but I need to ask: How? How do I do it exactly? I know that the general idea is to use ArrayList, but again, I'm a  noob.

Answer (score 0):

So try to write the program so that one value is read from the file. Store that value in a java variable and use this variable as required with webdriver. Then iterate over it as required.

I think the flow should be  like this.

- Read the xlsx file value with search engines (Iteration on Search Engines)
- use get to open the url
- iterate over the queries
- Repeat for next search engins

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the values which you are fetching from an excel file are name and mail-id.

Store both the values in their Data-type variables.

Lets say *name* and *mailid* are the two required variables.

Now create one method with the parameters created above to send it to web-page from Excel file.

Below is just the sample implementation how you can do it.

```
public static  void runTest(String name,String mailid) throws InterruptedException 
    {       
        System.out.println("Inputing name: "+name+" and mailid: "+mailid);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).clear();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(name);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(mailid);

        System.out.println("Inputted name: "+name+" and mailid: "+mailid);

        Thread.sleep(2000); // Sleeping 2 seconds so that each entry is detected.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Save values in a datastructure.
> 2. Iterate through the values.
> 3. Create a helper function which will pass value one by one in to Web driver.

**Pseudocode:-**

```
    //Instead of printing the values 
    //Save all the site in 
    List<String> sites = new ArrayList<String>(0);
    //Save all the queries in
    List<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>(0);
    for(String site : sites){
    System.out.println("Time consumed:- " + runQueriesForSite(site, queries));
    }




     private int runQueriesForSite(site, queries){
        int searchTime = 0;
        for(String query : queries) {
          searchTime += runQueryForSite(query, site); //Webdriver will use this function to connect and return result
         }
      return searchTime;
    }


int runQueryForSite(query, site)
{
//Hope you'll find the time calculation algorithm yourself
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get(site);

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys(query);

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
}
```